# Send transaction throw bsc with web3

Tags: web3js, transactions, javascript, bsc, binance

i'm trying to send a transaction via bsc using WalletConnect and web3

This is the connection code

```
    const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
  rpc: {
    1: "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/",
    2: "https://bsc-dataseed1.defibit.io/",
    3: "https://bsc-dataseed1.ninicoin.io/",
    // ...
  },
});

async function () {

  await provider.enable();

  //  Get Accounts
  web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
    if (error) alert(error)
    this.account = accounts[0]
  })
```

And this is the cransaction call

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
          to: '0x...',
          from: this.account,
          value: 1000000000000, //test value
        }, ((error, hash) => {
          if (error) alert(error)
          else console.log(hash)
        }));
```

The problem is that on my trust wallet the transaction is on the ETH blockchain, even if i can read my bsc token balance correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the network ID, not just the providers, not sure where but thats what you need to look for